# How to assign declared fields to records XML

Tags: xml, xslt

How to assign declared fields to items/records in XML in order to export it to simple CSV file

Manualy replacing items/records @id with @name field does the job but I'm looking for a XSLT who would help me reproduce the changes automaticaly

Original XML sample

```
<table id="1A" name="TableName" comment="">
 <fields>
    <field id="field1" name="name_of_field1" other_uselessatr="..."/>
    <field id="field2" name="name_of_field2" other_uselessatr="..."/>
    <field id="field3" name="name_of_field3" other_uselessatr="..."/>
 </fields>
 <records count="200">
    <rec num="1">
       <fld id="field1">value1</fld>
       <fld id="field3">value2</fld>
       <fld id="field2">value3</fld>
    </rec>
    <rec num="..."></rec>
 </records>
</table>
```

Desired result

```
<rec id="1">
  <name_of_field1>value1</name_of_field1>
  <name_of_field2>value2</name_of_field2>
  <name_of_field3>value3</name_of_field3> 
</rec>
...
```

Comment: Use a key: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a key:

```
  <xsl:key name="field-ref" match="fields/field" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="fld">
      <xsl:element name="{key('field-ref', @id)/@name}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

XSLT 3 sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7kP but the key should work the same with older versions of XSLT, you would need to spell out the identity transformation instead of using `xsl:mode` or perhaps you rather want to add more templates to perform other changes like

```
  <xsl:template match="rec/@num">
      <xsl:attribute name="id" select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

as done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7kP/1

Comment: @kretinus Note that there is an assumption here that your field names are valid XML element names. This may or may not be always true. The format you show as your input is the kind of format databases often use **because** they cannot guarantee that their field names *can* be used as XML element names. Be warned.